# Edit Image and Delete Row from GridView using c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to `Edit` and `Delete` `Row` of `GridView` using `C# ASP.NET`.

I tried once and able to fill the data in `TextBox` after `click` on `Edit Button`,But I have also one `Image` to `Edit` and what I need is when user will `click` on `Edit Image`, The `Image` will also `Display` in proper place to `Edit`.In case of `Delete` part I have `Image` in `Anchor Tag` and I need which event I should pass from `GridView` and define in code behind page so that I can do the operation.

> faq.aspx:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="question" accesskey="T"><span class="required">*</span> Question</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  size="30" value="" name="question" ></asp:TextBox>
    <div id="noty" style="display:none;" runat="server"></div>
    <label for="answer" accesskey="A"><span class="required">*</span> Answer</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  size="30" value="" name="answer" ></asp:TextBox>
    <div id="Div1" style="display:none;" runat="server"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile">
    <label for="insertimage" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Insert Image</label>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="insertimage" id="FileUpload1" onchange="previewFile()" />
    <label for="bannerimage" accesskey="V"><span class="required">*</span> View Image</label>
    <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;"   />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" class="submit" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<!--end_1st_faq_add_div-->
<!--2nd_list_banner_view_div-->
<div class="widget-area">
    <h2 class="widget-title"><strong>FAQ List</strong></h2><asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1"  runat="server" />
    <div class="streaming-table margin-top-zero padding-top-zero">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero" 
                onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl No">
               <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="faqid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FAQ_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question" >
               <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="question" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer" >
               <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="answer" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Answer") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" >
               <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;" ImageUrl='<%# "/Upload/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("Image")) %>'  /> 
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" >
               <ItemTemplate>
               <a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit" id="editbtn" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
<a href=" " data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

> faq.aspx.cs:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewSelectedIndex);
    TextBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
    TextBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
    HiddenField1.Value = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;
    Button1.Text = "Update";
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have only item temples in grid view. 
Hence I'm going to tell you two ways to do this:
1) Add edit template in grid view and handle the OnRowEditing event of grid view.
2) Add a hyperlink with key of row and link to another page where you can design the editor like you have done in this page by pre-populating the data using the key(primary key)

Comment: So how can i add row image in `<asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;"   />` after clicking on edit button.

Comment: There is a property called as ImageUrl. Populating that with image's address will automatically load the image

Answer (score 0):

it is better that you use Modern data control like 'entitydataSource' or 'linqdateSource' or 'sqlDataSource' and bind your gridview by them .
using 'itemtemplate' for all rows is not a good way , instead fill you grid with 'dataSource' and use 'itemTemplate' for delete or Edit Button . send button name As commandName and rowID As commandArgument to gridViewItemCommand event in code behind.

in code behindin in GridviewItemcommand_Event with switch statement loop through itemCommands like this :

```
int itemID = int.parse(e.commandArgument)
switch(e.commandName)
   { 
      case 'DoEdite' :{//some Code 
                       Viewstate["ID"] = itemID;
                       break;}

      case 'DoDelete' :{//some Code
                        break;}
   }
```

you have the itemID(e.commandeArgument) and know which button clicked(e.commandName) .so you can do what you want.
In edit Mode when you send data to textBoxes use viewstate or other collection to hold your dataID because of after Edit, for Update edited date 
you need it,

Comment: @ sajad : these code snnipet i have to write inside which method in `faq.aspx.cs` file and let me to know `Doedit`,`DoDelete` are the id name or what ?you mean i ahve to pass `GridviewItemcommand_Event` from GridView and define this in `faq.aspx.cs` instead of `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` right ?

Comment: yes , if you have problem i can make an Example for you

Comment: @ sajad : yes,please make an example based on above code.

Comment: OK , let me to write It in 10 min

Comment: @ sajad : sure friend.

Comment: @ sajad : Are you trying now ?

Comment: send me your email to send you the source

Comment: @ sajad : subhrajyotipradhan@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81763/discussion-between-satya-and-sajad-zarenejad).

Comment: for security reason I could not send source by email I upload it to my up load center and send you the link soon

Comment: go and click on cloud sign

Comment: did you got the file?

Comment: @ Sajad:Yes.Can I implement the same thing in `a` tag for do the edit and delete opreation.

Comment: you need a server side control to chain to server code . use linkbutton . this genrate <a> tag for you finally